# HtmlHelper to display only a few characters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, html-helper, spark-view-engine

Is it possible use a HtmlHelper to display only a few characters of the text? how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
public static MvcHtmlString SubString(this HtmlHelper helper, string theString, int length)
{
  return MvcHtmlString.Create(theString.Substring(0,length));
}
```